# load partial entityset ef4

Tags: entity-framework, ef4-code-only

Can I load only a few properties from an Entity?

As an example I have an entity with the following properties:

```
ID
DESCRIPTION
HEADER
PICTURE
```

I only want to load the IDs and not the other properties.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please never post in ALL CAPS. It's like shouting.

Comment: sorry, didnt notice the caps lock was on

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case if you just need the `ID`s, you can use the following query:

```
var ids = context.YourEntities.Select(e => e.ID).ToList();
```

You can also use projection (useful if you need to load more than one property):

```
var entitiesWithIdsAndHeaders = context.
                                YourEntities.
                                Select(e => new
                                            {
                                                Id = e.ID,
                                                Description = e.Description
                                            }).
                                ToList();
```

Comment: Or load it to a POCO class instead of an anonymous.