# Partial eager loading child entity (load specific fileds)

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, entity-framework-4

I searched a bit and understands that I can [use projection to partially load an entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5311678/load-partial-entityset-ef4) , the question becomes is there a way to partially eager loading a child?
Say I have the following

Entity A has

```
Id
Name
EntityB
```

and Entity B has

```
Id
StuffToBeLoaded1
StuffToBeLoaded2
OtherStuffNotToBeLoaded
```

How can I load A with B , and B only has stuffToBeLoaded1 and stuffToBeLoaded2?
I guess I cannot call .Inlucde("EntityB") otherwise it is fully loaded, is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use custom query with a projection. If `EntityB` property represents collection you can use something like:

```
var query = from a in context.EntitiesA
            select new 
               {
                  a.Id,
                  a.Name,
                  Bs = a.EntityB.Select(b => new { 
                       b.StuffToBeLoaded1, 
                       b.StuffToBeLoaded2 
                  })
               };
```

If `EntityB` is not a collection navigation property you can simply use:

```
var query = from a in context.EntitiesA
            select new 
               {
                  a.Id,
                  a.Name,
                  a.EntityB.StuffToBeLoaded1, 
                  a.EntityB.StuffToBeLoaded2 
               };
```